# Getting AVG B/W 2 TIMESTAMPS that requires comparing one date to the most recent date

Tags: mysql, sql

Hoping someone can help me out with a small SQL problem.

I have a group of users with a registration_date and an activity_date, that can have many values. Each of those columns are in different tables, users and activty, respectively.

I need to subtract the 2 dates, the registration_date the most recent activity_date. Then I want to be able to average the subtracted dates for all users in the table. And I only want to see the AVG for the users where the TIMEDIFF is >= 90

I've tried to use MAX(activity_date), as in

```
SELECT activity.user_id, AVG(TIMESTAMPDIFF (day,users.reg_ts, SELECT 
MAX(activity.actvy_ts FROM activity))) AS LifetimeAVG
FROM  activity JOIN users 
ON  activity.user_id =  users.user_id
WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF (day,users.reg_ts, activity.actvy_ts) >= 90
GROUP BY activity.user_id
;
```

but it throws a group error.

> ERROR: ER_INVALID_GROUP_FUNC_USE: Invalid use of group function

Comment: You cannot use one aggregate function `MAX()` in another aggregate function `AVG()`, because that does not make any sense. You will need to solve this using a Subquery (Derived Tables). Get max date first in the subquery, and then in outer query, average them out.

Comment: Thanks. Can you give me an example of how that might look?

Comment: Please edit the question and add a complete query, so that it can be modified accordingly.

Comment: edited, per request. thanks.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use one aggregate function `MAX()` inside another aggregate function `AVG()`, because that does not make any sense for a particular "group".

Instead, you will need to do first-level aggregation (`MAX`), at an inner subquery level ([Derived Table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-tables.html)), and then use the result-set for further aggregation (`AVG`):

```
SELECT Avg(dt.max_diff) AS LifetimeAVG
FROM   (SELECT u.user_id,
               Timestampdiff (day, u.reg_ts, Max(a.actvy_ts)) AS max_diff
        FROM   activity AS a
               JOIN users AS u
                 ON u.user_id = a.user_id
        GROUP  BY u.user_id, u.reg_ts
        HAVING max_diff >= 90) AS dt
```

Comment: Thanks. That's working. But I'm curious about the WHERE statement. It should be comparing the reg_ts to MAX(actvy_ts). How can I achieve that?

Comment: @Andrew make into a `Having` clause then

Comment: Can you explain how a Having clause works in this instance?

Comment: @Andrew check the updated query in the answer now. We use Having clause to filter out the cases where difference between the maximum (latest) activity time and registration time is less than 90. And, eventually we calculate average of only those cases where timediff is >= 90

Comment: @Andrew If the answer has worked for you, please see: [How to accept an answer for closure](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235). You get points for it as well. Thanks :)